# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$drawable Error when using ForceAuthDialog

Tags: android, xamarin.android, facebook-android-sdk

I noticed that after I updated my Monodroid SDK and tried to use the following:

```
facebook.Authorize(activity, FB_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.ForceDialogAuth, new LoginDialogListener());
```

I get this error: Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$drawable.

I uninstalled my Facebook App so that my app does not use SSO and will be forced to show the native Facebook SDK login dialog packaged with the SDK everytime.

The Facebook sample in the monodroid-samples folder has the same problem when I try to deploy it.

I read somewhere that I have to rename my namespace into `Com.Facebook.Android` to fix this. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the new Monodroid Facebook sample and got the latest build and it worked.